# Certbot lets-encrypt certificate not found after installation

Tags: apache, ssl-certificate, devops, lets-encrypt, certbot

Certbot installed two lets-encrypt SSL certificates but none working

On my AWS EC2 Ubuntu 18

Three files are as follows:

## /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www/html
ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =sub1.domain.net [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} =sub2.domain.net
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [END,NE,R=permanent]
</VirtualHost>
```

## /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default-le-ssl.conf

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
DocumentRoot /var/www/html
SSLEngine on

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

ServerName sub1.domain.net
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
ServerAlias sub2.domain.net
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/sub1.domain.net/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/sub2.domain.net/privkey.pem
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

## /etc/apache2/sites-available/default-ssl.conf

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost _default_:443>
ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost

DocumentRoot /var/www/html

ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

SSLEngine on


SSLCertificateFile      /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key


<FilesMatch "\.(cgi|shtml|phtml|php)$">
SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
</FilesMatch>
<Directory /usr/lib/cgi-bin>
SSLOptions +StdEnvVars
</Directory>
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>

 # vim: syntax=apache ts=4 sw=4 sts=4 sr noet
```

## /var/log/letsencrypt/letsencrypt.log

```
2018-12-21 04:51:46,545:DEBUG:certbot.reverter:Creating backup of /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default-le-ssl.conf
2018-12-21 04:51:46,744:INFO:certbot_apache.configurator:Deploying Certificate to VirtualHost /etc/apache2/sites-enabled/000-default-le-ssl.conf
```

## netstat -ltnp | grep ':80\|:443'

```
tcp6 0 0 :::443 :::* LISTEN      1529/apache2
tcp6 0 0 :::80 :::* LISTEN      1529/apache2
```

> I tried everything but the outside world doesn't find any certificate.
>   I didn't put any entry into this file: /etc/apache2/apache2.conf
>
> subdomains were taken from free DNS dynu dot com

Comment: The first thing that I notice is these two lines. Private Key for one domain and Certificate for another. `SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/sub1.domain.net/fullchain.pem`
`SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/sub2.domain.net/privkey.pem` What do the Apache log files show when loading the certificate?

Comment: Another issue is this line `ServerAlias sub2.domain.net`. You do not want ServerAlias for HTTPS. You want a separate section for each domain and its certificate.

Comment: What was the exact command that you used with Let's Encrypt?

Comment: [Sat Dec 22 03:55:04.288440 2018] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 9202] AH00171: Graceful restart requested, doing restart
[Sat Dec 22 03:55:04.404799 2018] [ssl:warn] [pid 9202] AH01909: sub1.domain.net:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name
[Sat Dec 22 03:55:04.404927 2018] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 9202] AH00163: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) OpenSSL/1.1.0g configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sat Dec 22 03:55:04.404934 2018] [core:notice] [pid 9202] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'

Comment: I used two seperate commands for two separate domains 

certbot-auto certonly --standalone -d sub1.domain.net
   and   
certbot --apache -d "sub2.domain.net" --server https://acme-v02.api.letsencrypt.org/directory

Comment: Your problem is described: `sub1.domain.net:443:0 server certificate does NOT include an ID which matches the server name `. Change this line: `SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/sub2.domain.net/privkey.pem` to `SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/sub1.domain.net/privkey.pem` and reboot the server. Then try `https://sub1.domain.net`

Comment: I got this error after changing the line as you advised:

-     [Sat Dec 22 05:10:07.401378 2018] [ssl:emerg] [pid 21402] AH02565: Certificate and private key sub1.domain.net:443:0 from /etc/letsencrypt/live/sub2.domain.net/fullchain.pem and /etc/letsencrypt/live/sub1.domain.net/privkey.pem do not match

Comment: Your SSL certificates are messed up. Start over with Let's Encrypt. Do one domain name. Once you have that work, add the second domain name.