# Telnet works on AWS URL and localhost but not on IP

Tags: amazon-web-services, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, telnet, tcp

## These are working fine:

```
telnet ec2-x-x-x-x.compute-1.amazonaws.com 443
telnet localhost 443
telnet internal.ip 443
telnet hostname 443
```

## These are not working

```
telnet x.x.x.x 443
telnet freedns.dynu.com 443
```

However telnet on port 80 works fine with all of them.

My AWS Ubuntu 18 box has a **/etc/hosts** file that reads

```
127.0.0.1 localhost

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1 ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
ff02::3 ip6-allhosts
```

netstat -ln says:

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.53:53           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3306          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:10000           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::443                  :::*                    LISTEN
tcp6       0      0 :::80                   :::*                    LISTEN
```

> What am I missing or where am I going wrong?
>
> Technically if *ec2-x-x-x-x.compute-1.amazonaws.com* is good then the IP
>   address should also be good.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not have a process (web server) listening on IPv4 port 80 or 443. You do have a process (web server) listening on IPv6 ports 80 and 443.

The problem is that your web server is either not setup for 0.0.0.0:80 and 0.0.0.0:443 or your web server failed during startup. Consult your web server logfiles.

These addresses could only have worked resolving IPv6 addresses.

```
telnet ec2-x-x-x-x.compute-1.amazonaws.com 443
telnet localhost 443
telnet internal.ip 443
telnet hostname 443
```

Comment: Thanks but which logfile should I check? Is it /etc/apache2/error.log ? Please help.

Comment: @KolkataCalcutta - Close this question and open a new one. Where to look depends on the type and version of your web server and how it is configured. Start here: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/38978/where-are-apache-file-access-logs-stored

Comment: I am wondering if you could help me with this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53879653/certbot-lets-encrypt-certificate-not-found-after-installation

Comment: Yes, I will take a look at the SSL configuration question.